# Vectorized running bin index calculation with Tensorflow or numpy

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have an integer array like this:

`in=[1, 2, 6, 1, 3, 2, 1]`

I would like to calculate a running index for the equal values in the array. For the matrix above the output would be:

`out=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]`

So the naive implementation would be to have a counter for all the values. I would like to have a vectorized solution to run it with tensorflow, perhaps with numpy.

I already thought of creating a 2D tensor of `shape=(in.shape[0], tf.max(in), )` and writing `1` to the `tensor[i, in[i]]` cell, and then call a `cumsum` column-wise, then writing back row-wise. But my input array is quite big (with several 100k entries) with the maximum value of ~500k, thus this sparse matrix wouldn't even fit into the memory.

Do you have better suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pandas solution:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 6, 1, 3, 2, 1])
s.groupby(s).cumcount().values
```

Output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Test on similar sized data:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,500000, 100000))
%timeit -n 100 s.groupby(s).cumcount().values
# 23.9 ms ± 562 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I tried using TensorFlow to do this and it got pretty ugly pretty quickly. So if it's few 100k, your better off using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an actual sparse matrix, i.e. use sparse storage. With that an input like `a = np.random.randint(0,5*10**5,10**6)` is no problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def running(a):
    n,m = a.size,a.max()+1
    aux = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones_like(a),a,np.arange(n+1)),(n,m)).tocsc()
    msk = aux.indptr[1:] != aux.indptr[:-1]
    indptr = aux.indptr[:-1][msk]
    aux.data[0] = 0
    aux.data[indptr[1:]] -= np.diff(indptr)
    out = np.empty_like(a)
    out[aux.indices] = aux.data.cumsum()
    return out

# alternative method for validation
def use_argsort(a):
    indices = a.argsort(kind="stable")
    ao = a[indices]
    indptr = np.concatenate([[0],(ao[1:] != ao[:-1]).nonzero()[0]+1])
    data = np.ones_like(a)
    data[0] = 0
    data[indptr[1:]] -= np.diff(indptr)
    out = np.empty_like(a)
    out[indices] = data.cumsum()
    return out

in_ = np.array([1, 2, 6, 1, 3, 2, 1])
print("OP example",in_,"->",running(in_))
print("second opinion","->",use_argsort(in_))

from timeit import timeit
A = np.random.randint(0,500_000,1_000_000)
print("large example (500k labels, 1M entries) takes",
      timeit(lambda:running(A),number=10)*100,"ms")
print("using other method takes",
      timeit(lambda:use_argsort(A),number=10)*100,"ms")
print("same result:",(use_argsort(A) == running(A)).all())
```

Sample run:

```
OP example [1 2 6 1 3 2 1] -> [0 0 0 1 0 1 2]
second opinion -> [0 0 0 1 0 1 2]
large example (500k labels, 1M entries) takes 84.1427305014804 ms
using other method takes 262.38483290653676 ms
same result: True
```